# Ruby on rails -Devise - Require password to delete account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords, destroy

Currently my users need to enter their password in order to change their email address or password, but can delete their account without entering it. I am not sure how to require this.

So far I have:

Users controller:

```
def destroy
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @user.destroy_with_password(user_params)
      if @user.destroy
          redirect_to root_url, notice: "User deleted."
      else
        redirect_to users_url
        flash[:notice] = "Couldn't delete"
      end
    end



    def user_params
         params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password,
                                      :password_confirmation, :current_password, :avatar, etc....etc.... )
    end
```

A form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, :method => :delete) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
      <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here the user deletes even if no password is inputted. The delete request is being processed by the correct controller action ;

```
Processing by UsersController#destroy as HTML

Processing by UsersController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bla bla bla", "user"=>{"current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update User", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"ce2dc2edc"}

SQL (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 15]]
```

How can I require the user's password in order to delete the account?

Comment: For people who don't know `@user.destroy_with_password(current_password)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling Devise's `destroy_with_password` **and** then calling ActiveRecord's `destroy`. You only need to call `destroy_with_password`. Code should read as follows:

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  if @user.destroy_with_password(user_params)
  # if @user.destroy      # <== remove me, don't need to destroy twice!
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "User deleted."
  else
    redirect_to users_url
    flash[:notice] = "Couldn't delete"
  end
end
```

`destroy_with_password` is going to return a [truthy value](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/d293e00ef5f431129108c1cbebe942b32e6ba616/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L102-L115).

Comment: Ok things are going better, but I'm getting a 'current password invalid message even though it's valid.