# Destroy_with_password always returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Building off of an existing question that [walks through how to require a password to delete a user account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373655/ruby-on-rails-devise-require-password-to-delete-account) using the Ruby gem Devise's `destroy_with_password`.

My destroy action looks like this:

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  if @user.destroy_with_password(user_params)
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "User deleted."
  else
      redirect_to root_url
      flash[:notice] = "Couldn't delete"
  end
end

def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :password, 
                                :password_confirmation, :current_password... (etc) )
end
```

and the form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The redirect works, but it redirects even when the correct password is inputted without deleting the account.

I run `binding.pry`, and `@user.destroy_with_password(user_params)` always returns false.

If I open `user_params` this is what is returned:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"current_password"=>"123456"} permitted: true>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official docs `destroy_with_password` accepts `current_password` argument, so instead of passing the whole `user_params` just pass the `current_password`, do this

```
@user.destroy_with_password(user_params[:current_password])
```

More info in rubydoc

[Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticatable#destroy_with_password](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FModels%2FDatabaseAuthenticatable:destroy_with_password)

Give it a try.