# Test does not delete user after password confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

I am writing a test to confirm the user account is deleted after the user inputs the correct password.

The form I am testing:

```rb
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :password %>Enter your password to delete your account.<br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_to_delete %><br />
  <button type="submit", data-test="delete-user-account">Delete my account</button>
<% end %>
```

([I can confirm the action works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454812/destroy-with-password-always-returns-false), but the test does not.)

This is my current test:

```rb
RSpec.feature 'user deletes account' do
  let(:user) { create :user }

  # when user puts in correct password and successfully deletes
  context 'when successful' do
    scenario 'user inputs correct password' do
      visit new_user_session_path
      fill_in 'user_email', with: user.email
      fill_in 'user_password', with: '123456'
      find('[data-test="submit"]').click
      visit edit_user_registration_path
      fill_in 'user_password_to_delete', with: '123456'

      find('[data-test="delete-user-account"]').click

      expect(user).not_to be_present
    end
  end
end
```

What gets returned:

```rb
Failures:

  1) user deletes account when successful user inputs correct password
     Failure/Error: expect(user).not_to be_present
       expected `#<User id: 1>.present?` to return false, got true
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on this but try

```
user.reload
expect(user).not_to be_present
```

Logical reason is user still persist as an variable but not in database.

alternatively you can use

```
user = User.find_by_id user 
#this will try to find the user from database which is already deleted and thus returning nil

expect(user).not_to be_present
```

Comment: It does not like `user.reload`, it returns with `Couldn't find User with 'id'=1` which is what I _want_. But that error fails the test.

`user = User.find_by_id user` still finds the user and returns true.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!

I checked for `User.last` before and after the delete section to be sure and that's what will return nil.

I even checked if I changed the password if it returned a false positive and it didn't.

Comment: It worked -> Good. Is it a clean solution -> No. Definitely need to find a cleaner solution.